is there a new NuGet package that replaces Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity?
I'm working on a Blazor server app, and I found out that Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity 2.2.0 NuGet package is deprecated. Is there a new package that replaces it? or something to make use of for customizing data about the logged in user? Thank you.
I did some web research for a potential answer but nothing so far.

Microsoft sure doesn't give much guidance (or, it hides it well)!

Check https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api and lookup the specific APIs you want to use.
For example, when I look up the UserManager class, at the top of the page it says:

Package:
Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core v8.0.0

Another example, when I look at the UserIdentity class it says "Package:
Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores v8.0.0"


I'm working on a Blazor server app, and I found out that
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity 2.2.0 NuGet package is deprecated. Is
there a new package that replaces it?

Well based on your scenario and description, It seems you haven't get the correct package. Because, its true that Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity 2.2.0 is no longer maintained.

Is there a new NuGet package that replaces
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity?

Yes, we do. Instead of using above version, you should have following nuget package for your latest version of app or more specifically, higher than .NET 7 and .NET 8:

Furthermore, you could download the package manually either from visual studio nuget package manager or even directly from nuget link.
But if you create a Identity Scaffold project, these package should integrate authomatically. As you can see below:


Something to make use of for customizing data about the logged in
user?

Well if you mean that you want to customize your asp.net Identity user class which is derived from IdentityUser, yes you can do that.
In order to customize Asp.net identity user class, all you need a new class and then inherit IdentityUser class into your newly created class. You can do as following:
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string YourNewCustomizedProperty { get; set; }
        
    }

Note: If you need details example, you could check here. In addition, please refer to this official document as well.
